# Create a user form with inputs for one entry with multiple parameters

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to create a user form that would allow to give one entry multiple parameters, resulting in a table that looks like this:

| fruit | colour(s) |
| --- | --- |
| apple | red |
|  | green |
| banana | yellow |
|  | brown |
|  | green |

Also to note, each entry should be able to have a range of parameters, anywhere from 1 to likely 10 at most. Desirably, it would also merge the empty cells with the entry, but this is not necessary. Is there a way to do this in excel without VBA? If not, where would I start with VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I think the user inputs a line of information and you want to build the above table.

so, for example the input could be:

A1:  Apples

B1:  red, green

then another entry could be

A1:  banana

A2:  yellow, brown, green

the below code can handle this with titles in A5 and B5 of Fruit and Colour(s) respectively:

```
Sub tableCreate()

    fruit = Range("A1").Value
    colours = Range("B1").Value
    coloursArr = Split(colours, ",")
    inputRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    For x = 0 To UBound(coloursArr)
        Range("A" & inputRow).Value = fruit
        Range("B" & inputRow).Value = coloursArr(x)
        inputRow = inputRow + 1
    Next x
    
    Range("A1").Clear
    Range("B1").Clear

End Sub
```

Hopefully this gets you started.  There are some efficiency savings to be had on this if it'll be used a lot but I just wanted to show a simple solution

[this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/assign-a-macro-to-a-button-728c83ec-61d0-40bd-b6ba-927f84eb5d2c) will help with putting a button on the sheet to enter the info.

Comment: Just to say I can't think of a non VBA solution but that's not to say there isn't one.  Also expansion of this to ten or more inputs will take some time but like I say, hopefully on the right track